# delete files and folders with VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel, delete-file, vba

Good day,

right now I am working on a small Excel VBA Sheet which should us help to prepare data for a CAD release change. All these files are saved on a network drive (server) but I have read and write permissions.
Everything is working right now except the final cleanup. After processing the files I have to delete the remaining folders and files (thumbs.db).

Unfortunately these files are created on server-side and I can't disable this setting.

I am looking for a VBA code to delete everything (files and folders) within a specific path. All I have right now is this: (saveto is coming from another module)

```
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
If Right(saveto, 1) = "\" Then
MyPath = Left(saveto, Len(saveto) - 1)
End If
On Error Resume Next
fso.deletefile saveto & "\*.*", True
fso.deletefolder saveto & "\*.*", True
On Error GoTo 0
```

But with this code I don't get rid of these stupid thumbs.db (which are created as "system files"). Anyone can help me with the last part?

Edit (marked as duplicate)
I would like to solve it with "filesystemobject"

Comment: The "thumbs.db" are some kind of system files. Instead of trying to delete them, I think you'd better try to avoid those files from being created, which of course means that you need to modify the configuration of your server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove directory and it's contents (files, subdirectories) without using FileSystemObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401789/remove-directory-and-its-contents-files-subdirectories-without-using-filesys)

Comment: @Dominique
I don't have admin access to our server configuration and our admin is kinda ... well he don't want to change anything because of this.
This cleanup is a unique process which don't will happen again so delete the files is the best (and only) option but I struggle with the code

Comment: I can't see what the problem is with your code. The [DeleteFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca0at0xh(v=vs.84).aspx) method should ordinarily delete a folder even if it has files (non-empty).  Is this not the case for you, because of the .db file extensions? Have you tried using `.DeleteFile` method in a loop over the folder's contents?

Comment: It seems that the Windows Explorer is locking this "thumbs.db" file. Gonna try to kill the Windows Explorer process, delete everything and restart the process ... our admin said he won't disable the automatic thumbs.db stuff -.-

Comment: Can you delete the `thumbs.db` files manually? This seem to be due to the permissions of the `thumbs.db` files, look at the properties of any of this files (right click on the file), in the tab `Security` check the permissions.

Comment: I think the thumbs.db files contain preview, for example, if you have the folder (or Windows itself) set to show thumbnails of image files instead of generic icons.

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this:

```
Sub delelete_folder()

Dim folder As Object
Dim path As String
path = ("E:\New folder\targetfolder")
Set folder = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    folder.deletefolder path, True

End Sub
```