# Microsoft Access Database for Microsoft Flight Simulator 2020

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm a Microsoft Flight Simulator 2020 Simmer, have been since it first came out back in 1982 or 83.  I'm creating an Access Database that allows users to save their Addon Aircrafts and Sceneries so that they have a record of what is installed in the database and what is not.  There is a program out in the Simming Community that allows a user to ADD (LINK) or UN-INSTALL (UNLINK) any Aircraft or Scenery that they have into and out of Flight Simulator 2020 that would possibly affect other addons and thus cause the Sim to either crash to the desktop (CTD) or hang (Freeze).

What I would like to do is build that into my Access Database so that the User can either Link or Unlink a particular aircraft or scenery to or from the Sim to prevent any conflicts with other addons.  If you are a Simmer like me then you'll know exactly what I'm talking about.  I know of several ways to copy folder to other folders, but these are specific and have to be hard coded into the VBA Coder in access to check a particular Drive and path and see if the folder that is specified is in that location.  I want them to be able to choose what drive to copy a particular folder from and paste it into the Community Folder where all aircraft and sceneries are stored for the Sim.

Then, once the user is finished with either the aircraft or scenery un-install it (Unlink) from the Community Folder and allow it to be deleted or removed so that it doesn't conflict with other addons.  I have seen it done in other programs for MSFS 2020 but don't know where to begin on how to code this, summary:

Addon Aircraft/Scenery - copy this folder (FolderName) to ---> Community Folder (Link)
Addon aircraft/Scenery - Delete (FolderName) from Community Folder (Unlink).

Again, the User of the database gets to choose whatever folder they want to to Link from, and choose the Community Folder to Unlink from when finished.

I've tried different types of copying to but like I said before it is hard coded, but I want to choose which folder and not have to hard code it because everyone using the Sim will have different locations to where they have their aircraft or scenery folders.

Comment: Your question is too broad and not appropriate for SO. Use of File System Object is a common topic and many examples. Research it and when you have code with specific issue, post question.

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735583/delete-files-and-folders-with-vba-excel

Comment: To the one who sent me the link to "VBA - selecting a folder and referencing it as the path for a separate code" excellent idea!!!! You understood what I was needing and gave me exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for understanding, as for the other answer directing me to "stackoverflow..." thank you as well.  Don't do too much with VBA in Excel but it did give something to think about.  Thank you both for your guidance and comments.

Comment: Excel or Access, VBA code for FSO should be same.

Comment: As I have never used it in Excel I never knew that, thank you for the clarification.