# vba remvoving Directory

Tags: vba, recursion

Have a bit of a brain teaser.
How do you delete a directory with all its contents, including all sub folders, all files, etc.

I have the following code that has a recursive call, but it only deletes leaf folders.

It deletes all files and it deletes leaf folders (last nodes).

Anybody know of a way to kill one whole path in VBA, including all files and folders?

Maybe there is an easier way than recursion....
Thanks...

```
Sub DeleteFiles()


    Call RecursiveFolderDelete("C:\tmp1")

    'RmDir ("C:\tmp1")


End Sub

Sub RecursiveFolderDelete(MyPath As String)

    Dim FileSys As FileSystemObject
    Dim objFolder As Folder
    Dim objSubFolder As Folder
    Dim objFile As File

    'On Error GoTo 0

    Set FileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(MyPath)

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If Left(objFile.Name, 1) <> "~" And objFile.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
            objFile.Delete
        End If
    Next objFile


    Dim Count As Integer
    Count = 0
    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        Count = Count + 1
        RecursiveFolderDelete MyPath & "\" & objSubFolder.Name
    Next objSubFolder
    If Count = 0 Then
        RmDir MyPath
    End If


    Set FileSys = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objSubFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You should check out [Remove directory and it's contents (files, subdirectories) without using FileSystemObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401789/remove-directory-and-its-contents-files-subdirectories-without-using-filesys)

Comment: No, I don't think that code is accurate.  If you have c:\tmp1 and within tmp1 you create a complicated nested structure of folders and files, I want to be able to delete the whole thing....  this code does not do that.  And what is mkdir all about?  So the code Does Not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the folder

```
On Error Resume Next
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set file = fso.GetFolder("C:\test")
File.delete
```

This part is pointless as everything is set to nothing at every `End Sub/Function`.

```
Set FileSys = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objSubFolder = Nothing
Set objFile = Nothing
```

Comment: If you have c:\tmp1 and within tmp1 you create a complicated nested structure of folders and files, I want to be able to delete the whole thing....  this code does not do that.    Delete all files and all subfolders.  and all files in subfolders.  And all subfolders within subfolders. And so on..... So basically c:\tmp1 should not exist after the delete.

Comment: By the way, I disagree with the negative ratings.  The question HAS NOT been answered before.  See comments above.  I did not see an answer that works.

Comment: If you have nested folders then two things have happened. You removed security blocks on some folder links. Or you need to run chkdsk.