# Run mkdir with same folder name immediately after deleting a folder

Tags: excel, vba

If "INDIA" folder does not exist, I can create the folder.

After I delete the folder "INDIA" with rmdir, I cannot create a folder named "INDIA", it gave me an error, "path/file access error".

```
saveFolder = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\Daily\INDIA\"
If Dir(saveFolder, vbDirectory) <> "" Then
   CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").DeleteFolder(ActiveWorkbook.path & "\Daily\INDIA")
   MkDir (saveFolder)
else
   MkDir (saveFolder)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added an Extra `\` at the End of your `saveFolder`

This will work:

```
saveFolder = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Daily\INDIA"

If Dir(saveFolder, vbDirectory) <> "" Then
   CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").DeleteFolder (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Daily\INDIA")
   MkDir (saveFolder)
Else
   MkDir (saveFolder)
End If
```

Also make sure that Folder `Daily` Exists.

Comment: Hi, Mikku, thank you for the reply. yes directory Daily exists. However, this still does not work. now i am using the code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401789/remove-directory-and-its-contents-files-subdirectories-without-using-filesys. However, i realize i cannot do mkdir right after rmdir. it only works if i run the code two times